# Error while creating test and train dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The **datasets** file contains images of cars and trucks. All images of cars are in one file and all images of trucks are in another file. The file containing the car images is called **Car** and the file containing the truck images is called **truck**. I am trying to create subfolders **test** and **train**. The train file should contain 80% of shuffled car and truck images from the dataset and the test file should contain 20% of shuffled car and truck images from the dataset. I have tried using the os method for the same but an error pops up. The code and the error for the same are as given below.

**CODE:**

```
import os 
import shutil
import random
import glob         
os.chdir('C:/Users/akash/Downloads/Datasets')
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('car*'),200):
    shutil.move( c, 'train/car' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('truck*'),200):
    shutil.move( c, 'train/truck' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('car*'),100):
    shutil.move( c, 'test/car' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('truck*'),100):
    shutil.move( c, 'test/car' )
os.chdir('../../')
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9e77a796540b> in <module>
----> 1 for c in random.sample(glob.glob('car*'),200):
      2     shutil.move( c, 'train/car' )
      3 for c in random.sample(glob.glob('truck*'),200):
      4     shutil.move( c, 'train/truck' )
      5 for c in random.sample(glob.glob('car*'),100):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in sample(self, population, k)
    361         n = len(population)
    362         if not 0 <= k <= n:
--> 363             raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    364         result = [None] * k
    365         setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list

ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

Comment: The errors says that you have specified a population size `(i.e) 200`, which is larger than the actual size of the population it is trying to sample from `(i.e) images of cars`. How many images of cars do you have ? Try reducing the sample size.

Comment: The car file has 290 images of cars. The same goes for the truck file. I also tried reducing the sample size and the same error pops up.

Comment: From your description `All images of cars are in one file`, what is this single file ? Is it a directory ? Is it a pickled file ? I believe that's what's causing the error.

Comment: By file I mean a folder. Sorry for misinterpreting the same.

Comment: Could you add your folder structure to your description ?

Comment: So inside the `datasets/cars ` directory you have another directory ?

Comment: Yes. The folder structure is ` C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets` for the **datasets **folder. For the **car** folder, it is `C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\car` and for the **truck** folder it is `C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\truck`.

Comment: I want to know whether there is another directory inside `C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\car` which consists of the 290 car images or is it within `C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\car` this directory.

Comment: It is within this directory C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\car

Comment: Could you run this code `len(glob.glob("./car/*"))` and ``len(glob.glob("./truck/*"))`` within your `C:\Users\akash\Downloads\Datasets\` directory and tell me the outputs ?

Comment: I'll do that and let you know, Thanks.

Comment: Hey, should we add the last line `os.chdir('../../')`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. But run those two lines below `os.chdir('C:/Users/akash/Downloads/Datasets')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232879/discussion-between-user13973948-and-kishore).

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('car*'),200):
```

to this

```
population = glob.glob('car*')
for c in random.sample(population,200):
```

**set a breakpoint on the second line and when it hits, check the value of `population`, especially the length. It needs to be >= 200.**

Comment: Well, yes, it would. Did you not read the last sentence of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the directory in which the glob module should look for is not specified in the correct format. Make sure you have the directories `'train/car'`, `'train/truck'`, `test/car` and `test/truck` within your current directory. Change your code to the code snippet below.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import os 
import shutil
import random
import glob         
os.chdir('C:/Users/akash/Downloads/Datasets')

if not os.path.isdir('train/car'):
    os.makedirs('train/car')
if not os.path.isdir('train/truck'):
    os.makedirs('train/truck')

if not os.path.isdir('test/car'):
    os.makedirs('test/car')
if not os.path.isdir('test/truck'):
    os.makedirs('test/truck')

for c in random.sample(glob.glob('./car/*'),200):
    shutil.move( c, 'train/car' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('./truck/*'),200):
    shutil.move( c, 'train/truck' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('./car/*'),100):
    shutil.move( c, 'test/car' )
for c in random.sample(glob.glob('./truck/*'),100):
    shutil.move( c, 'test/truck' )
os.chdir('../../')
```

Comment: I have done the same and a different error came up. The error is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train/car`. Could you please help me out? Is it because I haven't created a file called train?

Comment: I changed the forward slashes to backward slashes. Could you try the code again once ?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal `

Comment: @user13973948 Yes, try creating the directory and `'train/car'` and `'train/truck'`. And please try the code once again. The one with forward slashes.